# How can I add a condition on the way of .append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
$.each(cities.cities, function (i, item) {
    $('select#city').append($('<option>', {
        value: item.id,
        text : item.name
    }));
});
```

Now I need to add a condition on the way of appending. I mean I want to add `selected` attribute to that option which has the same `item.id` as `city_id` variable. How can I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with my question?

Comment: Where do you talk about?

Comment: Just add another property to the object you're passing: `{ ..., selected: item.id == cityId }`

Comment: @stack I haven't downvoted, but I would say "lack of own attempt". The jQuery documentation and thousands of examples all over the internet show how to set the select box value with jQuery, it's completely impossible that you haven't found anything about it, unless you haven't really looked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selected` is boolean property - which can be the result of a conditional:

```
$.each(cities.cities, function (i, item) {
    $('select#city').append($('<option>', {
        value: item.id,
        text : item.name,
        selected: item.id === city_id
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to set the `selected` attribute **only if** `item.id === city_id` evaluates to `true`, one way of doing this is the following:

```
$.each(cities.cities, function (i, item) {
    /* Create a data object. */
    var data = {
       value: item.id,
       text : item.name,
    };

    /* Check whether the ids are equal. */
    if (item.id === city_id) data.selected = "";

    /* Use the data object to create the option and append it. */
    $('select#city').append($('<option>', data));
});
```

The above will produce:

```
<option value = "..." text = "..." selected/>
```

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
var
  city_id = 2,
  cities = [
    {id: 1, name: "Amsterdam"},
    {id: 2, name: "Athens"},
    {id: 3, name: "Berlin"}
  ];

$.each(cities, function (i, item) {
  /* Create a data object. */
  var data = {
     value: item.id,
     text : item.name,
  };

  /* Check whether the ids are equal. */
  if (item.id === city_id) data.selected = "";

  /* Use the data object to create the option and append it. */
  $('select#city').append($('<option>', data));
  
  /* Log the created option. */
  console.log($('select#city').children().last()[0]);
});
```

```html
<!---- HTML ----->
<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "city"></select>
```

Comment: I havent downvoted your answer, but I suspect it is because it is overly verbose - there is no harm in passing `selected:false` (it produces the expected html without the `selected` attribute).

Comment: Selected is a boolean property https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-selected - while `""` might work it would be more reliable/compatible to use a boolean value. Given the more awkward/verbose implementation and not adhering to the expected boolean value makes the answer less useful. IMHO.

Comment: Agreed @Jamiec. My answer aims to solve the problem in a very specific way which, however, I clearly state before providing the code.

Comment: I'm well aware of the spec @Fran, but thanks for the link; it may prove useful to someone who stumbles upon this answer in the future. Personally, I prefer this way to have a _less verbose_ HTML. Thanks for sharing your opinion!

Comment: My apologies it didn't seem you were.